# Jar file naming conventions

Tags: java, jar, naming-conventions

Are there any industry standard conventions for naming jar files?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I have been using

```
*Informative*-*name*-*M*.*m*.*b*.jar
```

Where:

*M* = `major version number` (changed when backward compatibility is not necessarily maintained)

*m* =  `minor version number` (feature additions etc)

*b* = `build number` (for releases containing bug fixes)

Comment: Example: apache-ant-1.6.5.jar . Note that a hyphen is used as the word separator, not underscore.

Answer (score 2):

If your jar is used for JEE then [these guidelines](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html) apply:

> The module name is used as the EJB archive name. By default, the
>   module name should be based on the package name and should be written
>   in all-lowercase ASCII letters. In case of conflict, the module name
>   should be a more specific version (including other part of the package
>   name):
>
> EJB archive:  -ejb.jar
>
> EJB client archive:  -ejb-client.jar