# Should the version be appeared in the name of .jar files?

Tags: java, jar, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jar file naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119426/jar-file-naming-conventions)

Currently, I've decided to standardize the name of my .jar files. In many projects, the version of the .jar files appear in the name, e.g. richfaces-3.0.1.jar. Is it a good naming style or should I mention the version of the .jar file in its manifest? If it is better, should I use this style for my internal releaseses?

Comment: @John: I had seen that post before and I do not think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Version numbers in your jars. Look at pages like http://mvnrepository.com/. When you download a huge number of jars it can happen quite often that two jars are dependend on the same lib with different version numbers. Using the Version number in your jar file helps tools that are used in your toolchain.