# When should a jar file name have a version number in it? What are the pros and cons of this?

Tags: java

I'm new to java.  When I look at jar files, I see a mix of including version in the file name and not.

- Under what circumstances is either of these a good idea?
- What are the pros and cons of putting a version number in a jar file name?
- If a version is in a jar file name, do client jars need to be recompiled to make use of it?

I've looked around for this information, but I've mostly found prescriptive direction, rather than thoughtful explanation.  [This link](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/05/java-jar-file-naming-conventions-and.html) is a little bit helpful, but [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119426/jar-file-naming-conventions) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7403994/should-the-version-be-appeared-in-the-name-of-jar-files) so questions aren't really.

Comment: @rgettman, Is a more specific explanation of why a question is closed too much to ask?  This is a question that is not easily answered elsewhere, and does not seem subjective to me.  I feel I demonstrated that I'd researched the question elsewhere?  I was not satisfied with the several other unhelpful SO questions (should you version? yes, no matter what) and wanted to understand what forces prompt either choice.  Is stackoverflow the wrong place to go to get a detailed answer on a technical question?  Is it unreasonable to expect feedback on the closing of a question?

Comment: FWIW I think it's a perfectly reasonable question. Egomaniacs closing questions without giving reasons is not helpful at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Versioned jar-files are always a good idea
2. The version is immediately visible & you can easily spot conflicts. I can't see any substantial* con.
3. No, name of jar-files matters only if you have conflicting class files in two or more jar-files**.

<sub>*: E.g., insignificat cons, such as executable jars might be easier to type without version numbering</sub>

<sub>**:
E.g., if you have the class `com.foo.Bar` in two jar-files, the classloader will load either one, typically depending on which is finds first. The same applies if you have two versions of the same jar - you will typically not know which version will be used.</sub>

Comment: Can you elaborate on 3?

Comment: If you keep those jars in one folder and you update references to those jars manually in your IDE, you can end up having newer/older version than your collegue. So, I suggest using maven for that. 
Also, it is easier to get two versions of the same jar in your project (instead of replacing the file "mylib.jar", you might accidentally add one ("mylib-1.0.jar" with "mylib-1.1.jar").
Again, if you are using maven or another project management tool, it should not be an issue.

Comment: I'm confused.  If I have two versions of the "same" jar available (but different file names due to versioning) the one that is used is **arbitrary**? That seems terrible.

Comment: @tallseth, welcome to java classloading, never keep duplicates! :)

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for subjective opinions.... and I have a subjective opinion on this. I maintain the JDOM project. We have a number of jars, and in the early years of the project, we had versionless jar names. Now we have a versioned jar name.

The reasons we switched are:

- It is easy to see what jar version you in your classpath (makes debugging and communication easier)
- It is easy to ask user's what version they have (makes bug reporting easier)
- it is easy to store multiple jars in a single directory (makes management easier)
- many 'library' resource systems (like maven) require the version number in the jar

Reasons I have heard for having a versionless jar (but I don't agree with)

- shorter class paths - too many classes can overflow command-line lengths. This is a BS argument, and the same problem can be encountered by having a lot of Jars. Can be solved with a manifest file in a special Jar. Not the versioned jar's fault.
- easy to drop in a new jar version (overwrite old jar) - well, there's nothing stopping you from renaming the jar yourself, or updaing your build system to reference the new jar version. In fact, you have more control of your build process if you define your jars vy version number.

There is no reason I have encountered where it is compelling that a versionless jar is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, good idea, use Maven http://maven.apache.org/ and it will build jar with version automatically, no cons pros only

Comment: That sounds nice but I am much more interested in an analysis of why to choose one convention over another, rather than prescriptive advice to do x or y.

Answer (score 1):

The only con I'm aware of is when you're building jar files that are executed on a workstation or executed as a part of a script.

You can get around this by including a script file with your jar file.

Here's a Windows example:

application.cmd

```
java.exe application_2013_05_10.jar
```

When you update the jar file, you update the script file(s) at the same time.  Users execute the application.cmd script file.